# MvvmCross (Android) appears to be keep hold of ViewModels and never disposing, what am I missing

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mvvmcross

If using MvvmCross you have a very simple view-model that subscribes to a message via the MvxMessager, even when the view it is on is disposed, the view-model remains in memory and still receives these messages. I managed to replicate it in a very simple app by putting a few receivers on Activities/Fragments that are later destroyed, but when the the message is sent via another action, the view models appear to still be alive? If the same View-Model is navigated to and then closed multiple times, the message is received by each instance of the View Model created.

I should point out these are weak references I am using for MvxMessenger, and there are no static references in my view models and I am explicitly disposing of my Activities via Dispose.

This looks to be a problem with all of the MvvmCross samples (TipCalc/Star Wars) as well.

I could just unsubscribe manually but I would have hoped the Weak Reference token from MvxMessenger avoids this.

Steven

Answer (score 3):

Because the View you are using is disposed does not necessarily mean that the associated ViewModel is disposed. Xamarin uses multiple ways to achieve garbage collection. You can read more about garbage collection in Xamarin apps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/deploy-test/memory-perf-best-practices#use-the-sgen-garbage-collector).  With Sgen for example, a garbage collection occurs when a specific Heap runs out of space. With that in mind, if your app does not use a lot of memory, it could take a significant amount of time until your viewmodels are effectively disposed.

There are a few best practices that you can use to prevent that:

- For ViewModels, dispose of your subscriptions when the ViewModel is not visible on screen anymore. More often that never, you don't want to update UI while a screen is not visible on screen. I usually subscribe to events in `ViewAppearing` and unsubscribe in `ViewDisappearing`.
- [optional] Determine if multiple instances of a specific ViewModel can exist concurrently. In Instance, Can you ever have multiple instances of LoginViewModel exist concurrently? In that case, you can implement logic that ensure that only a single instance of a ViewModel can have a subscription for a given message and `purge` the old subscription. 
  You can purge old subscriptions for a message type by using:

  MvxMessengerHub.RequestPurge(typeof(TStoreMessage));

The best way to understand how the [MvxMessengerHub](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/develop/MvvmCross.Plugins/Messenger/MvxMessengerHub.cs) works, or MvvmCross in general, it to read its source code.